# How should I handle partial EntityCache hits in Siesta?

Tags: ios, siesta-swift

I have an endpoint where I can request multiple pieces of data (such as `https://example.com/things?ids=1,2,3`) that I'm querying using Siesta.  I'm trying to figure out the proper behavior of my persistent entity cache if I only have some of the `things` cached. So, if I have thing 1 and thing 2, but not thing 3 cached, I'd like to return a partial hit and have Siesta also query my server with the original URL.  However, my understanding is that if `EntityCache.readEntity` returns anything, then Siesta assumes that the query was fully fulfilled, and does not continue on to make the network request.

Is there a good way for me to implement a partial hit, or do I need to return `nil` from `readEntity` and wait for a response from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your cache return the partial content with an `Entity.timestamp` in the distant past. (It’s fine to use zero.) This will cause the 1,2 partial content to appear immediately on launch and when offline, but `loadIfNeeded()` will consider that content stale and thus still trigger the request for 1,2,3.